# GetStream: Watching (creating) a channel after it has been delete will show an error

Tags: react-native, getstream-io, getstream-chat

When I try to **delete** a **channel**, the user that belongs to that channel is also deleted. Then when I **watch** (or **create**) a new **channel** with the **same user,** I get the following error:

> Error: StreamChat error code 4: **GetOrCreateChannel** failed with
> error: "The following users are involved in channel create operation,
> but don't exist : [...user_id]. Please create the user objects before
> setting up channel.

I want the app to behave just like in Facebook (messenger) where deleting a channel will also delete all the messages that is included in that specific channel.

Then creating a brandly new channel with the same  user should work correctly without the above error.
(I used the same code as describe in the official docs for deleting a channel) [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react-native/channel_delete/?language=javascript#deleting-a-channel).